# amp project form submit

Tags: forms, amp-html

I'm currently testing a landing page made with amp.
There's a lot of information on how to make forms but,
nothing on how the form is process.

Where we insert the recipient email?
Do we need to make a submiter.php?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a server endpoint to handle the form submission. If you use `method="POST"` then you should also add `action-xhr="submitter.php"` and then `submitter.php` should collect the values in the form, and return JSON to the AMP page.

If you use `method="GET"` then you can use `action="submitter.php"` or `action-xhr="submitter.php`. If you use `action` and not `action-xhr` then `submitter.php` doesn't need to return JSON, it can just be a normal PHP/AMP page that takes the values of the form and sends an email or whatever you want